# DAX Filter context

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I am wondering what the difference is between these two DAX expressions which each return what I need:

```
(1) =calculate([PctMkt], FILTER ( ALL ( BondDim), BondDim[Quality] = "HY" ))
```

```
(2) =calculate([PctMkt], ALL(BondDim), BondDim[Quality] = "HY" )
```

Does the DAX engine make these two expressions equivalent? Is (2) just short hand for (1)? Also, would (1) calculate more quickly? Trying to make sure that I don't cause problems in the pivot table by "hacking" together  calculated measures. These measures allow the user to drilldown to a lower grain while keeping higher level data in context of the pivot table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler, similar question is well-known.

```
CALCULATE (
    [PctMkt],
    BondDim[Quality] = "HY"
)
```

[is the shortened equivalent of](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/managing-all-functions-in-dax-all-allselected-allnoblankrow-allexcept/)

```
CALCULATE (
    [PctMkt],
    FILTER (
        ALL ( BondDim[Quality] ),
        BondDim[Quality] = "HY"
    )
)
```

---

Your formulas need a bit more thought.

When ALL is used as an argument of CALCULATE, it only removes filters (like [REMOVEFILTERS](https://dax.guide/removefilters/)) rather than acting as a table expression.

When `ALL ( < table > )` is used as an argument of FILTER, it is necessarily a table expression.

The first link I gave gives a detailed example of how this distinction can make an important difference. I'll provide another example here:

Suppose `MarketDim` has a one-to-many relationship with `BondDim` (and is *not* bidirectional) on the `ID` column from each and the tables are as follows:

```
  BondDim          MarketDim

Quality   ID       ID    Pct
-------------      ----------
HY        1         1    5%
VY        1         2    10%
XY        2         3    20%
```

Let's suppose `[PctMkt] := MAX ( MarketDim[Pct] )`

Then, in your first formula `(1)`, the FILTER argument is the following table:

```
Quality  ID
-------------
HY       1
```

Thus, the result of `(1)` can only be `5%` (or blank) since `ID = 1` is the only option.

In your second formula `(2)`, there are no table arguments since `ALL ( BondDim )` is only removing filters and `BondDim[Quality] = "HY"` only acts on a single column. Without table arguments, since `MarketDim` filters `BondDim` but not vice versa (since it's a single direction relationship), neither of these column filter arguments has any effect on the measure I've defined (it might on your actual measure though).

Thus, the result of `(2)` is the same as just `CALCULATE ( [PctMkt] )`, which will be `20%` unless there is filtering on `MarketDim` to exclude `ID = 3`.

Note: This simplification for `(2)` does not hold if `[PctMkt]` operates on `BondDim` columns or any table columns that are filtered by `BondDim` in your model. I.e. the filters propagate "downstream" across relationships but not "upstream".

Answer (score 1):

The second one

```
CALCULATE (
    [PctMkt],
    ALL ( BondDim ),
    BondDim[Quality] = "HY"
)
```

is internally expanded by DAX as the equivalent formula

```
CALCULATE (
    [PctMkt],
    ALL ( BondDim ),
    FILTER (
        ALL ( BondDim[Quality] ),
        BondDim[Quality] = "HY"
    )
)
```

So it is not the same as the first one

```
CALCULATE (
    [PctMkt],
    FILTER (
        ALL ( BondDim ),
        BondDim[Quality] = "HY"
    )
)
```

The difference is that the first one uses the whole BondDim table as a filter while the second one is using just one column of the same table